# how to disconnect a windows share dir by known IP?

Tags: windows, networking

windows only record 1 user/pwd to a remote share dir,

and my program need to connect a dir,

but the user may login first, let my program failed to connect,

is there a method to disconnect it? i only know the IP.

I use wnetcancelconnection2(remotedir) first, but still cannot work,

and return 1219 error(credentials supplied conflict with an existing set of credentials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the NetUseDel function?

[NetUseDel Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370646%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
net use \\\10.0.0.1\sharename /user:domain\user
```

to disconnect

```
net use \\\\10.0.0.1\sharename /delete
```

Comment: How can I do it programatically using WNetAddConnection2A (pinvoke) in C# ?

Answer (score 1):

To disconnect one single computer/ip from a share. Use net session \IPADDRESS OR NAME /Delete or Net Session /delete to disconnect all client connections. You must run this command from the server which holds the share that is being connected to.

Of course im not quite sure i read your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your CMD window needs to be run with Admin rights. Found a more detailed explanation here:

http://the-chronicon.blogspot.com/2015/01/disconnect-mapped-network-shares-via-cmd.html